# things to make you anxious

Tags: adverbs, postmodification

a. He'll tell you things **to make you anxious**.

I think 'to make you anxious' postmodifies 'things'. Would you agree with that?

The sentence means:

b. He'll tell you things **that will make you anxious**.

and not:

c. He'll tell you things **in order to make you anxious**.

(c) doesn't make sense. You can't make someone anxious just by telling them 'things'.

Would you agree with that?

Many thanks.

Comment: "You can't make someone anxious just by telling them 'things'" Depends what the 'things' are.

Comment: Your example (c) makes perfect sense. Suppose I wanted to make a person anxious, for some reason, e.g. because I felt like being cruel to them, or wanted to sell them something. I could tell them things like their hair is falling out, they look unwell, they seem to have put on weight, their car's engine sounds rough,, they might have bad breath or body odour, a recession is coming,  etc. People do this all the time. A large part of the advertising industry is based on telling people things in order to make them anxious. Also many politicians do it, e.g. by arousing fears in people.

Comment: The hearing aid consultant assisting me is doing her best to make me anxious about all the bad things that will happen in my life if I do not invest in one of her devices, preferably the most expensive one.

Comment: @RonaldSole - What? Speak up! Why does everybody mutter these days?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Forgive me, I didn't quite catch that.

Comment: @RonaldSole - the mutter remark was my grandmother, verbatim, and my father used to bellow 'YOU'RE DEAF, MOTHER!'. Happy days.

Answer (score 2):

Your example (c) makes perfect sense. Of course you can make people anxious by telling them things.

Suppose I wanted to make a person anxious, for some reason, e.g. because I felt like being cruel to them, or wanted to sell them something. I could tell them things like their hair is falling out, they look unwell, they seem to have put on weight, their car's engine sounds rough, their baby looks unwell, they might have bad breath or body odour, a recession is coming, their new neighbour has been in jail, etc.

People do this all the time. A large part of the advertising industry is based on telling people things in order to make them anxious. Also many politicians do it, e.g. by arousing fears in people.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I say 'I'll give him books in order to make him cheerful.' does that mean that I want to give him books that will cheer him up, or that I want to give him books (maybe not cheerful books, maybe scientific books, maybe tragedies, maybe books that have sad content) because I know receiving books make him happy. In other words does my sentence define the type of book I will give him? Or does it mean "I will give him books, because getting books cheers him up." (He might be a collector and not even read the books). I hope my question is clear!

Comment: @azz - your sentence does not define the type of book, and it could mean either that the contents or types of books made him cheerful, or the mere fact of being given books.

Answer (score 1):

"(c) doesn't make sense. You can't make someone anxious just by telling them 'things'."

Sorry, but that is simply not true.

"I've hired an assassin to kill your wife. He should be on his way right now."

"I overheard your boss saying that he is going to fire you."

"I poisoned the food you ate for lunch."